# Any way to add value into existing rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am still not so good with SQL query and can't find answer via Google too !

I got table with existing data and a very complicated data like several values with ASCII code in between .

At SQL Table, it will just appear as space

But It wont work if I just copy the value from that Column and use update statement as there are some ASCII chars acting as space ( for e.g. if you copy from Column,it will appear as ValueA ValueB ValueC but in reality,it is something like ValueA+0+7+7+1+7+ValueB

Long explanation ..

So What I need to do now is add new value into that Column 
If needed ,I can add this new value with ASCII too since ASCII number are fixed
I need the query to be something like

```
Update DB-1
set Data=(select Prob_ColumnA from DB-1) +0+7+7+1+7+'New Value'
```

Comment: Please provide the schema of your table.

Comment: Your task is not clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: By `add` do you mean to concatenate to the existing value.  What is the `SQL type` of this field?

Comment: Please post the DDL of your table and expected result. A test data will help a lot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please pay attention to the tags you use; they offer a definition of what it means when you add it. If your question is about SQL Server, the `mysql` tag is not applicable. They are not the same thing, and they are not SQL syntax compatible in many ways.

Comment: Thanks for all the reply. This is the Column I need to add value in -> [ALERTS] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL . I am trying to add/update the value into above column without changing existing data .. basically i m trying to do like Update DB1 set Alerts=( select alerts from DB1 ) + New Static Data . There are thousand of entry in Alerts Columns though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to publish more details about your database to get a good answer.  Assuming the table name is DB-1 and the column name is Prob_ColumnaA, the following might help you find what you're looking for:

```
UPDATE DB-1
SET Prob_ColumnA = Prob_ColumnA + 'New Value'
```